# How to create a database if the database is not present?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a database if the database is not present, but it shows some error.

This the code that I am using:

```
{ 
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
        exit;
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname);

    if(!$db_selected)
    {
        $db_selected = " CREATE DATABASE $dbname ";
    }
}
```

This is the error that i get:

> mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on
>   line 2 Reading one value from empty results

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Can you update full code for above where have you used mysql_fetch_row in code?